How to pass Exception in sync riverpod provider?
I have a provider which throws an exception which I want to handle where I read the provider:
@Riverpod(dependencies: [firebaseAuth])
User currentUser(CurrentUserRef ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).currentUser;
  if (user == null) {
    throw UserNotSignedInException();
  }
  return user;
}

and I want to catch it here:
try {
  ref.read(currentUserProvider);
  resolver.next();
} on UserNotSignedInException {
  logger('User is not logged in, pushing intro route');
  router.push(const IntroRoute());
}

But the Exception is thrown inside the provider and never reaches the catch block. Does somebody know how to pass the exception so I can handle it in the try catch? I know when using AsyncValue that I get an AsyncError to handle but I don't want an async provider.

Why don't you make the provider type nullable (User?) and return the result itself?
If user == null then do what you wanna do...
Besides using AsyncValue, I don't think there's another way to catch errors that were thrown from the provider...

I did not want to handle a nullable or async object everywhere I want to use it although I know it's available.

You could wrap your User object inside an UserState object with both the User and the Exception or Èrror.
For example something like this:
class UserState {
  final User? user;
  final Error? error;

  final get bool isOk => user != null && error == null;

  UserState.success(required this.user);
  UserState.error(required this.error);
}

And then in your code:
@Riverpod(dependencies: [firebaseAuth])
UserState currentUser(CurrentUserRef ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).currentUser;
  if (user == null) {
    return UserState.error(UserNotSignedInException())
  }
  return UserState.success(user);
}

and
final userState = ref.read(currentUserProvider);
if (state.isOk) {
  resolver.next();
} else {
  logger('User is not logged in, pushing intro route');
  router.push(const IntroRoute());
}

This way, your provider always returns a valid state, whether the User could be obtained or not.

Or skip all that, and just use a completed FutureOr value, so that the User gets wrapped in an AsyncValue which can hold the error separately.

But I would still need to handle a asyncvalue inside a widget tree everywhere I want to use it. Although I know the value is available. Just making it nullable would be easier to handle I think but I wanted to avoid that too which is why I want to throw an exception.

But technically User IS nullable, you don't always have a value. If you want to avoid coding with a nullable object, you can use an empty/loggetOut User() object. Riverpod is an state management solution and the best choice here is considering that every outcome is a different state.

In my case it made most sense to just throw the Exception inside the try catch block. I want to do this because I want to make sure that a user is logged in and don't want to handle a nullable User object.
@override
void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
  try {
    final user = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      throw UserNotSignedInException();
    }
    resolver.next();
  } on UserNotSignedInException {
    logger('User is not logged in, pushing intro route', name: 'IntroGuard');
    router.push(const IntroRoute());
  } catch (e, s) {
    logger(
      'Error navigating to intro route',
      error: e,
      stackTrace: s,
      name: 'IntroGuard',
    );
    router.push(const IntroRoute());
  }
}

